# Non-clustered indexes for columns defined within a composite Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, database-design, index, performance, sql-server-2016, query-performance

I have a multi-tenant database where I am utilizing an `AccountId` column within all tables as a part of the composite Primary Key for tenant isolation. Is it beneficial to create additional non-clustered indexes on each column that is part of the composite Primary Key to assist SQL Server with maintaining accurate statistics and improving query performance when joining to lookup tables?

For instance, within an associative table that defines one-to-many relationships between an `Account` and the American `State` in which they have offices, *in theory* which of the two options is preferable given the following structure and sample query?

**Create the `Account` and `State` tables and populate with sample data.**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Account];
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[State];

-- [Account] table and sample values.
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Account]', 'U') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account] (
        [AccountId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        ,[AccountAlias] [varchar](3) NOT NULL
        ,[AccountName] [varchar](128) NOT NULL
        ,CONSTRAINT [PK_Account] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AccountId] ASC)
        ,CONSTRAINT [UQ_Account_Alias] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([AccountAlias] ASC)
        ,CONSTRAINT [UQ_Account_Name] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([AccountName] ASC)
    );

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Account] ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Account] ([AccountId], [AccountAlias], [AccountName])
    VALUES (1, 'SA1', 'Sample Account 1'), (2, 'SA2', 'Sample Account 2'), (3, 'SA3', 'Sample Account 3')

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Account] OFF;
END;
GO

-- [State] table and sample values.
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[State]', 'U') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[State] (
        [StateId] [tinyint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        ,[StateCode] [varchar](2) NOT NULL
        ,[StateName] [varchar](32) NOT NULL
        ,CONSTRAINT [PK_State] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StateId] ASC)
        ,CONSTRAINT [UQ_State_Code] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([StateCode] ASC)
        ,CONSTRAINT [UQ_State_Name] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([StateName] ASC)
    );

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[State] ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[State] ([StateId], [StateCode], [StateName])
    VALUES (1, 'AL', 'Alabama'), (2, 'AK', 'Alaska'), (3, 'AZ', 'Arizona'), (4, 'AR', 'Arkansas'), (5, 'CA', 'California')

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[State] OFF;
END;
GO
```

**Create `AccountState` OPTION 1 - composite Primary Key only**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[AccountState];

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[AccountState]', 'U') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AccountState] (
        [AccountId] [int] NOT NULL
        ,[StateId] [tinyint] NOT NULL
        ,CONSTRAINT [PK_AccountState] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AccountId] ASC, [StateId] ASC)
        ,CONSTRAINT [FK_AccountState_Account] FOREIGN KEY ([AccountId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Account]([AccountId])
        ,CONSTRAINT [FK_AccountState_State] FOREIGN KEY ([StateId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[State]([StateId])
    );

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AccountState] ([AccountId], [StateId])
    SELECT A.[AccountId], S.[StateId]
    FROM [dbo].[Account] A CROSS JOIN [dbo].[State] S
    WHERE A.[AccountId] = 1 AND S.[StateId] IN (1, 2, 3)
    UNION
    SELECT A.[AccountId], S.[StateId]
    FROM [dbo].[Account] A CROSS JOIN [dbo].[State] S
    WHERE A.[AccountId] = 2 AND S.[StateId] IN (3, 4, 5)
    UNION
    SELECT A.[AccountId], S.[StateId]
    FROM [dbo].[Account] A CROSS JOIN [dbo].[State] S
    WHERE A.[AccountId] = 3 AND S.[StateId] IN (1, 3, 5)
END;
GO
```

**Create `AccountState` OPTION 2 - composite Primary Key + non-clustered indexes**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[AccountState];

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[AccountState]', 'U') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AccountState] (
        [AccountId] [int] NOT NULL
        ,[StateId] [tinyint] NOT NULL
        ,CONSTRAINT [PK_AccountState] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AccountId] ASC, [StateId] ASC)
        ,CONSTRAINT [FK_AccountState_Account] FOREIGN KEY ([AccountId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Account]([AccountId])
        ,CONSTRAINT [FK_AccountState_State] FOREIGN KEY ([StateId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[State]([StateId])
        ,INDEX [IX_AccountState_Account] NONCLUSTERED ([AccountId])
        ,INDEX [IX_AccountState_State] NONCLUSTERED ([StateId])
    );

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AccountState] ([AccountId], [StateId])
    SELECT A.[AccountId], S.[StateId]
    FROM [dbo].[Account] A CROSS JOIN [dbo].[State] S
    WHERE A.[AccountId] = 1 AND S.[StateId] IN (1, 2, 3)
    UNION
    SELECT A.[AccountId], S.[StateId]
    FROM [dbo].[Account] A CROSS JOIN [dbo].[State] S
    WHERE A.[AccountId] = 2 AND S.[StateId] IN (3, 4, 5)
    UNION
    SELECT A.[AccountId], S.[StateId]
    FROM [dbo].[Account] A CROSS JOIN [dbo].[State] S
    WHERE A.[AccountId] = 3 AND S.[StateId] IN (1, 3, 5)
END;
GO
```

**Sample query**

```
SELECT
    A.[AccountName]
    ,S.[StateName]
FROM
    [dbo].[AccountState] A_S
    JOIN [dbo].[Account] A
        ON A_S.[AccountId] = A.[AccountId]
    JOIN [dbo].[State] S
        ON A_S.[StateId] = S.[StateId]
WHERE
    S.[StateCode] = 'CA'
```

Of the two options, what type of index combination would be seen as most suitable to scale? Composite primary key only or composite primary key plus additional non-clustered indexes? Or is there another option that is more viable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that the sample query is a fair example to base a recommendation on. The sample query is not a typical multi-tenant *application* query since it is not specific to a particular client. It is more of a support or management query looking to gain insight about all (or at least multiple) customers. Of course, it could also be maintenance related (e.g. garbage collection would look for oldest dates and not care about `AccountId`). So let's separate this out:

1. **General**

   I don't see any benefit to ever having a non-clustered index that is solely the leading / left-most key column in the clustered index. The clustered index is already in that order and so statistics exist for it. So, the `IX_AccountState_Account` index in Option 2 is purely waste, and a drag on the system.
2. **Support / Management / Maintenance queries**

   These queries, especially the maintenance ones, *can* work across `AccountId` values. As such, some queries will certainly benefit from non-clustered indexes on clustered index key columns *that are not `AccountId`* (or to put it more generally: that are not the left-most / leading key column). This assumes that you have queries that filter / sort on *only* the entity ID. Not having any queries like that means you probably don't need this index.
3. **Application queries**

   These queries should ***always*** include `AccountId`, so I don't see how they would benefit from an index that is solely on the entity ID.

   While I have worked on multi-tenant systems similar to what you are describing, I just thought of something that never occurred to me before: since the clustered index statistics are based on the left-most / leading column and not the combination of key columns, it *might* be beneficial to manually create statistics for those objects. I seem to recall that it is just the density portion that will account for all key columns (not just the leading column), but that might help the query optimizing. This needs to be tested as I have not tried it (and I won't be able to do such a test anytime soon).

Comment: I agree that the sample query isn't the best example as I shared a stripped down table set to be as concise as possible with a hopeful emphasis on the `JOIN`s to the lookup tables. My uncertainty was whether the leading key column would be utilized when it is the _only_ column of the `ON` clause. It appears it will use it per point 1. Following that, it  seems that `StateId` would need an NCI to assist with the `JOIN`. Point 2 will be something to dig into on a query-by-query basis per the execution plans. Point 3 has been ingrained into all my developers - _always_ include `AccountId`.

Comment: @PicoDeGallo Whether or not to add a NCI on `StateId` is part of Point 2. Only do it if you have cross-customer queries that filter / order based on `StateId`. But it shouldn't be needed for queries like the sample query because it is the given value that will be looked-up in the parent table. I don't believe it would be used in the context of the sample query, but you should test on your system with your data (actuall execution plan, not estimated) to see if it is used. I am also curious if the manual stats on the same composite keys as the clustered index helps.

Comment: Indeed, I should have clarified. I was leaning towards needing the NCI based off of existing queries within the system that do perform such a `JOIN` as opposed to the sample query. We have several associative tables where we have a composite Primary Key where the secondary column is a lookup table (such as `State`). At present we do not have any NCI on these table columns, but I will be carrying out a deeper performance analysis to see if SQL Server will positively leverage them. I will try to report back with my findings when I've reached that scope of work.